# ExecuteScalar() with SqlTransaction

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to do two inserts into a database using sqltransaction and executescalar to return the output ID of the first insert.

This is the code:

```
try
    {
      using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
         {
           conn.Open();

           SqlTransaction safetransaction = conn.BeginTransaction();

           foreach (var dado in NFSe)
              {

                SqlCommand cmd_NFSe = new SqlCommand("SqlCommand", conn, safetransaction);


                var newID = cmd_NFSe.ExecuteScalar();

                foreach (var serv in Servico)
                   {

                     string ID = newID.Tostring(); 

                     SqlCommand cmd_NFSeServ = new SqlCommand("SqlCommand", conn, safetransaction);


                     cmd_NFSeServ.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   }                                

               }
          }
     }

 catch (SqlException ex)
     {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
     }
```

But this is not working. Nothing is inserted into the database and I get no error or exception, just nothing happens.

If I use the same code but without the sqltransaction, everything works great.

Any ideas?

Comment: Consider using `ExecuteNonQuery()` instead of `ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: You need to commit the transaction. Do it after you're done with the inserts (I'm not sure where that should be because your question says "two inserts" but the code implies there could be many more than two). The code would be `safetransaction.Commit();`. Also, if you want to kill the transaction in case of an exception, put a `safetransaction.Rollback();` in your `catch` code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need call `safetransaction.Commit();`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Working great now.

Answer (score 1):

You Missed So many things

1. Commit trasaction
2. Rollback Transaction

> The transaction is rolled back on any error, or if it is disposed
>   without first being committed

just try this:

```
try
    {
      using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
         {
           conn.Open();

           SqlTransaction safetransaction = conn.BeginTransaction();

           foreach (var dado in NFSe)
              {

                SqlCommand cmd_NFSe = new 
                SqlCommand("SqlCommand", conn, safetransaction);
                cmd_NFSe.Connection = connection;
                cmd_NFSe.Transaction = transaction;

                var newID = cmd_NFSe.ExecuteScalar();

                foreach (var serv in Servico)
                   {

                     string ID = newID.Tostring(); 

                     SqlCommand cmd_NFSeServ = new 
                     SqlCommand("SqlCommand", conn, safetransaction);


                     cmd_NFSeServ.ExecuteNonQuery();
                     cmd_NFSe.Commit();
                   }                                

               }
          }
     }

 catch (SqlException ex)
     {

        cmd_NFSe.Rollback();
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
     }
```

Comment: consider adding some explanation. A code only answer is deemed to be of low quality.

Answer (score 1):

I wish you showed some of your SQL so we could see what you're doing but I have to assume you have an identity column you are getting the new id back from. I like to avoid multiple trips to the server so you might be well-to-know that you can combine multiple SQL statements in one call by separating them with ";". All statements within that single call are transactional as well so your overall code will be smaller and with a reduced number of trips to the server, faster too.  IE:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyField) VALUES ('Test1'); Select SCOPE_IDENTITY(); INSERT INTO MyTable (MyField) VALUES ('Test2'); Select SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Now use this with a DataAdapter.Fill and you will get a DataSet with 2 tables, each having the new ID for the inserts.

Oh, to your original question, you need to commit your transaction: `safetransaction.Commit();`